# Limiting file size in FormFile

Tags: go

I'm letting users upload a file using FormFile.  At what point should I check if the file size is too large.  When I do

```
 file, header, fileErr := r.FormFile("file")
```

A file object is already created.  So have I incurred the cost of reading in the entire file already?

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http#Request.FormFile

Answer (score 20):

Use [http.MaxBytesReader](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#MaxBytesReader) to limit the number of bytes read from the request.  Before calling ParseMultiPartForm or FormFile, execute this line:

```
 r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, max)
```

where `r` is the `*http.Request` and `w` is the `http.Response`.

MaxBytesReader limits the bytes read for the *entire* request body and not an individual file. A limit on the request body size can be a good approximation of a limit on the file size when there's only one file upload. If you need to enforce a specific limit for one or more files, then set the MaxBytesReader limit large enough for all expected request data and check [FileHeader.Size](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#FileHeader.Size) for each file.

When the http.MaxBytesReader limit is breached, the server stops reading from the request and closes the connection after the handler returns.

If you want to limit the amount of memory used instead of the request body size, then call [r.ParseMultipartForm(maxMemory)](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseMultipartForm) before calling `r.FormFile()`. This will use up to `maxMemory` bytes for file parts, with the remainder stored in temporary files on disk. This call does not limit the total number of bytes read from the client or the size of an uploaded file.

Checking the [request Content-Length](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ContentLength) header does not work for two reasons:

- The content length is not set for chunked request bodies.
- The server may read the entire request body to support connection keep-alive.  Breaching the MaxBytesReader limit is the only way to ensure that the server stops reading the request body.

Comment: `http.MaxBytesReader()` expects an `io.ReadCloser`, so `r.Body` should be passed instead of just `r`: `r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, max)`

Comment: This will limit the total request (including all fields + headers + files combined). If you only want to limit each file (and not the number of files) use [r.ParseMultipartForm(MaxSize)](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseMultipartForm). Keep in mind you might need both to be safe from attackers uploading 100 different 10MB files in one request.

Comment: How to use this with gin-gonic library?

Answer (score 16):

Some people are suggesting to rely on `Content-Length` header and I have to warn you not to use it at all. This header can be any number because it can be changed by a client regardless of the actual file size.

Use [MaxBytesReader](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#MaxBytesReader) because:

> MaxBytesReader prevents clients from accidentally or maliciously
>   sending a large request and wasting server resources.

Here is an example:

```
r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, 2 * 1024 * 1024) // 2 Mb
clientFile, handler, err := r.FormFile(formDataKey)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return
}
```

If your request body is bigger than 2 Mb, you will see something like this: `multipart: NextPart: http: request body too large`

Comment: Because the net/http server limits read on the request body to the length specified in the content-length header, a malicious client does not gain anything by specifying small content-length.  That said, MaxBytesReader is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Calling `FormFile` calls [`ParseMultiPartForm`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseMultipartForm), which will parse the entire request body, using up to 32M by default before storing the contents in temporary files. You can call `ParseMultiPartForm` yourself before calling `FormFile` to determine how much memory to consume, but the body will still be parsed.

Th client may provide a `Content-Length` header in the [`multipart.FileHeader`](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#FileHeader) which you could use, but that is dependent on the client.

If you want to limit the incoming request size, wrap the `request.Body` with [`MaxBytesReader`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#MaxBytesReader) in your handler before parsing any of the Body.

Answer (score 1):

You have `r.ContentLength int64` field in request struct and `r.Header.Get("Content-Length") string` method. Maybe that can help.

Comment: content-length can be tamper by malicious user, I would not use that