# Gin If `request body` bound in middleware, c.Request.Body become 0

Tags: go, middleware, go-gin

My API server has middle ware which is getting token from request header.
If it access is correct, its go next function.

But request went to middle ware and went to next function, `c.Request.Body` become `0`.

**middle ware**

```
func getUserIdFromBody(c *gin.Context) (int) {
    var jsonBody User

    length, _ := strconv.Atoi(c.Request.Header.Get("Content-Length"))
    body := make([]byte, length)
    length, _ = c.Request.Body.Read(body)
    json.Unmarshal(body[:length], &jsonBody)

    return jsonBody.Id
}

func CheckToken() (gin.HandlerFunc) {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        var userId int

        config := model.NewConfig()

        reqToken := c.Request.Header.Get("token")

        _, resBool := c.GetQuery("user_id")
        if resBool == false {
            userId = getUserIdFromBody(c)
        } else {
            userIdStr := c.Query("user_id")
            userId, _ = strconv.Atoi(userIdStr)
        }
    ...
        if ok {
            c.Nex()
            return
        }
}
```

**next func**

```
func bindOneDay(c *gin.Context) (model.Oneday, error) {
    var oneday model.Oneday

    if err := c.BindJSON(&oneday); err != nil {
        return oneday, err
    }
    return oneday, nil
}
```

`bindOneDay` return error with `EOF`. because maybe `c.Request.Body` is `0`.

I want to get `user_id` from request body in middle ware.
How to do it without problem that `c.Request.Body` become 0

Comment: I don't understand what "c.Request.Body is 0" means. c.Request.Body is an io.ReadCloser--`0` is an impossible value for an io.ReadCloser. Can you elaborate on what you mean? Do you mean that the value read from the body is the string `"0"`? Or do you mean that it's 0-bytes long? Or something else?

Comment: @Flimzy sorry `c.Request.Body.Read` not `c.Request.Body`

Comment: `c.Request.Body.Read` is a function, not an integer. Are you saying _that_ returns `0` as the number of bytes read?

Comment: @Flimzy yes `fmt.Println(c.Request.Body.Read(body))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only read the Body from the client once. The data is streaming from the user, and they're not going to send it again. If you want to read it more than once, you're going to have to *buffer* the whole thing in memory, like so:

```
bodyCopy := new(bytes.Buffer)
// Read the whole body
_, err := io.Copy(bodyCopy, req.Body)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
bodyData := bodyCopy.Bytes()
// Replace the body with a reader that reads from the buffer
req.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(bodyData))
// Now you can do something with the contents of bodyData,
// like passing it to json.Unmarshal
```

Note that buffering the entire request into memory means that a user can cause you to allocate unlimited memory -- you should probably either block this at a frontend proxy or use an `io.LimitedReader` to limit the amount of data you'll buffer.

You also have to read the entire body before Unmarshal can start its work -- this is probably no big deal, but you can do better using `io.TeeReader` and `json.NewDecoder` if you're so inclined.

Better, of course, would be to figure out a way to restructure your code so that buffering the body and decoding it twice aren't necessary.

Comment: Thanks @hobbs ! solve this problem. I learned a lot from your comment!

Comment: If you'd like please teach me how to use `io.LimitedReader`. I don't understand even googled this method.

Comment: @rluisr this might help [Limiting amount of data read in the response to a HTTP GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38874756/678491)

Comment: @biosckon thanks comment. this code is return `0`. Do you know what is wrong? https://play.golang.org/p/40c6XQ44ESz

Comment: @rluisr if you have solved it, please post answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Gin provides a native solution to allow you to get data multiple times from `c.Request.Body`. The solution is to use `c.ShouldBindBodyWith`. Per the [gin documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.ShouldBindBodyWith)

> ShouldBindBodyWith ... stores the
> request body into the context, and reuse when it is called again.

For your particular example, this would be implemented in your middleware like so,

```
func getUserIdFromBody(c *gin.Context) (int) {
    var jsonBody User

    if err := c.ShouldBindBodyWith(&jsonBody, binding.JSON); err != nil {
        //return error
    }

    return jsonBody.Id
}
```

After the middleware, if you want to bind to the body again, just use `ctx.ShouldBindBodyWith` again. For your particular example, this would be implemented like so

```
func bindOneDay(c *gin.Context) (model.Oneday, error) {
    var oneday model.Oneday

    if err := c.ShouldBindBodyWith(&oneday); err != nil {
        return error
    }
    return oneday, nil
}
```

The issue we're fighting against is that `gin` has setup `c.Request.Body` as an `io.ReadCloser` object -- meaning that it is intended to be read from only once. So, if you access `c.Request.Body` in your code at all, the bytes will be read (consumed) and `c.Request.Body` will be empty thereafter. By using `ShouldBindBodyWith` to access the bytes, gin saves the bytes into another storage mechanism within the context, so that it can be reused over and over again.

As a side note, if you've consumed the `c.Request.Body` and later want to access `c.Request.Body`, you can do so by tapping into gin's storage mechanism via `ctx.Get(gin.BodyBytesKey)`. Here's an example of how you can obtain the gin-stored Request Body as `[]byte` and then convert it to a string,

```
    var body string
    if cb, ok := ctx.Get(gin.BodyBytesKey); ok {
        if cbb, ok := cb.([]byte); ok {
            body = string(cbb)
        }
    }
```